# Is it possible to convert HDMI to DVI to VGA?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have a laptop with HDMI. I also have a monitor I got from my dad, it is old and it only accepts VGA. I have a DVI to VGA converter connected to it already. I was wondering if I used a HDMI to DVI converter and connected it to the DVI to VGA converter, would I still be able to have a dual monitor setup. I was looking at this eBay item as a HDMI to DVI converter that I will use: [Ebay HDMI to DVI](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/321865452985?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT)

Is it possible to connect HDMI to DVI to VGA monitor input for a dual monitor setup?

Comment: You have it backwards. You cant to convert *from* HDMI *to* VGA.

Comment: Seems like some answers presume some facts that are not in this post.  What exactly is this  *"DVI to VGA converter connected to it already"*?

Answer (score 3):

The adapter you found on eBay is a (minor) fraud. It cannot provide DVI-I. It can only provide DVI-D. DVI-I is a combined connector for both DVI-A (essentially VGA) and DVI-D. HDMI is only compatible with DVI-D. **If you connect a DVI-VGA adapter to the one from eBay, you won’t get any picture at all.**

So you need something else to convert HDMI to VGA, and that something is an active converter. For convenience, I’ll just copy the link from Chavez’ answer: [https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Active-Adapter-Support/dp/B008O7RH5C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008O7RH5C)

Answer (score 2):

No, unless you want a terrible picture.

Since you're converting a digital signal to an analog signal, you need a powered converter box to make this work properly. HDMI and DVI are also completely different digital technologies, and HDMI requires the box to separate the different signals it can send (HDMI supports video, 3D video, audio, and networking signals over the same cable as of 1.4a).

Something like this is what you need, paired with the proper VGA cable for your monitor (female-male or male-male): [https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Active-Adapter-Support/dp/B008O7RH5C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008O7RH5C)

I hope this works out well for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This *should* be a comment but I don't have the reputation to post them

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCFYSB0g-i8 I think that this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Please don't try to circumvent the comment restrictions by submitting an answer, that's not how the Stack Exchange model works. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: We expect answers here at Superuser to be text based.  Linking to a YouTube video is not an acceptable answer by itself.  If you wish to explain, in specific detail what the video explains, and use it only as a reference that is fine